# How to find table dependencies in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I created a table which contains both primary as well as foreign keys. Now i wants to know what are the tables which refers my table element as foreign key.

For example, `student` is a table which contains `id (primary key), name` element. And `standard` is an another table which contains `class_id (primary key), and stud_id (Foreign key refers student table id field)`. When i give student table and id field as input, it returns standard table as output. Please suggest me how can i achieve this???

Answer (score 2):

Well here is the link of solution of your problem.

[How do I see all foreign keys to a table or column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column)

[mysql innodb: describe table does not show columns references, what does show them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893168/mysql-innodb-describe-table-does-not-show-columns-references-what-does-show-th)

check it.

Answer (score 0):

ok, few things are missing, you didn't tell how you are trying to achieve this, what operating syatem you are using, you want to do it using script? if so what langauge, what dbms are you using? Let me know and you answer will be ready

ok here it is, you can delete last line if you prefer

```
SELECT standard.ID
FROM student INNER JOIN standard ON student.ID = standard.stud_id
GROUP BY standard.ID;
```

Comment: Am using Linux(Fedora) and i want to achieve this by using sql queries.